# Tomcat is not serving static content within application directory

Tags: pdf, tomcat, static-content, tomcat9

I am using Tomcat 9.0.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 running on java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.
The application serves a page which contains a URL to pdf file that supposed to display a pdf file in a browser when user clicks on the link. The pdf file resides inside application directory. The directory structure is as follows

```
webapps/RimWeighting
    ├── index.jspx
    ├── indexTrimmingOptions.jspx
    ├── indexWithTableOfUploadedFiles.jspx
    ├── javadocs
    ├── META-INF
    ├── userDocs
    │   └── User Doc.pdf
    └── WEB-INF
```

When browser queries a URL of the pdf file, it gets following response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"1164848-1330098906000"
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Feb 2012 15:55:06 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 1164848
Date: Sat, 07 Apr 2018 21:44:57 GMT
Connection: close
```

but no content. There is no error in the logs. I can’t figure out what the problem is. Application was migrated from Tomcat 6, where it worked. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: All looks good : you have the correct Content-Type header, and a Content-Length of 1MB which is probably the right size. It might be a "ghost" instance of PDF reader in your browser, did you try restarting it ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same on tomcat 9.0.7, and got my PDF served without any issues.Worked like a charm on chrome, IE and mozilla. 
this appears most likely to be an issue with browser.
Which browser are using?